# Concerning magic and the replacement of the four traditional elemants with the four fundamental forces

Tags: magic, physics, science-in-society

In a world of magic where spells are not based on fire, water, air, and earth; rather, the electromagnetic force, the gravitational force, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force—How do things work?

<s>I am aware that this is an incredibly broad question and one that has been asked many times before, but I feel that the room for creative thought is tremendous and I believe we'd all benefit from each other's interpretations.</s>

Okay, okay, too broad. I'm sorry. To explain what I mean by *magic* and what causes it to *exist*, magic in this context can be defined as a (fictional) ability of human intent and perception to drastically alter probability of natural processes at the level of those fundamental forces, up to the extent of creating macroscopic phenomena that should not logically be possible *in our world*.

Comment: but this big room of creativity prevents this question to be answerable, try to be more specific, how do you imagine the spells to work? To behave? As @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica says, what is the difference between your worlds spell and our worlds electric devices?

Comment: Why are you calling the real world "magic"? Those four/three/two/one fundamental forces are what makes the real world work. (Exactly how many are there depends on how you see physics; the electromagntic, weak and strong forces are already unified, and the gravitational force may be considered a force or not.)

Comment: "*In a world of magic where spells are not based on fire, water, air, and earth;*" just a note - we need more of these worlds and/or less of the "four elements magic". The "four elements" never really worked IRL when the ancient Greek used them. Later on somebody thought it would make for an OK magic system and...now we have this as a standard, somehow, even when no two works of fiction really agree what these elements should do. Even entries *from the same franchise* will put the same spell as part of a different element.

Comment: OK, as others have said, this is _way_ to broad a question! Maybe think of an effect that you want (e.g. a fireball), and then think/ask how would that be described with the 4 forces?

Answer (score 2):

> How do things work?

They work very, very simply: it is the world where you live in now.

Any weapon that we have is based on one or more of the 4 fundamental forces or its usage.

What you call spell is just the sequence of steps one need to execute to produce and fire the weapon. Some are more long, complex and powerful (aka thermonuclear bombs), some other are more short, easy and less powerful (aka a slingshot).